# Difficulty with printing output of TCL script which initializes and checks out with REPO

Tags: build, automation, tcl, checkout, repository

I have written TCL script to initialize and check out the latest repo directory from google. But it does not print anything in the terminal. I have tried open.

For open:

when initializing I have this... and it works fine

```
 if { [ catch { set ID [ open "|repo init -u *android_stuff* "] } cErr ] } {
     puts "Error initializing (${cErr})" }

 while { ![ eof ${ID}] } {
     gets ${ID} Line
     puts "Line: ${Line}" }
```

when checking out similarly....but this does not print a thing...

```
 if { [ catch { set ID [ open "|repo sync -j **"] } cErr ] } {
     puts "Error checking out (${cErr})" }

 while { ![ eof ${ID}] } {
     gets ${ID} Line
     puts "Line: ${Line}" }
```

I tried to implement it with "exec" but similar to "open" I couldn't print it.

Comment: Does it actually synchronize? (I wonder what the behavior of `repo` actually is; there are various ways in which things could be going wrong, some of which are *very* tricky indeed.)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `while` loop in an `else` clause: if you catch an error, you only print a message and continue on as if there's something valid in `$ID`

That use of `eof` reads one line too many: see http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html#eof